# ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] returns internal IP?

Tags: asp.net, .net, ip, request.servervariables

Since changing my server hosting to a new provider (ovh),
I don't manage to get the client's IP using a simple `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"]` .
It always returns 10.0.1xx.2xx (masked the exact value, don't know if that matters) which seems like an internal server IP to me.

Calling `Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"]` and `Request.ServerVariables["LOCAL_ADDR"]` gives the same results.

The code is called from withing Global.asax if that is relevant.

Any idea ?

Comment: Looks like it returns you their internet gateway IP address, probably the one like a Microsoft ISA server

Comment: Yes, but any solution for that ? how to retrieve the real IP using Asp.NET ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had same problem today with OVH.

Seems `Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REMOTE_IP"]` return the good ip